# transfer data via bluetooth IOS 7

Tags: ios7, bluetooth

iOS 7 Transfer Via Bluetooth problem

I used bluetooth to transfer text messages on iPhone
My application worked well with iOS 6.x or lower, but not worked well with device using iOS 7.x
I can still connect via bluetooth but cannot transfer text messages:
+) device using iOS7 cannot send to iOS7
+) device using iOS6 cannot send to iOS7

(**Note**: from device using iOS7 still can send to device using iOS6)

The link below is sample code: 
https://github.com/akashani62/BluetoothTextMessenger

Please help me solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise the use of Core Bluetooth or Multipeer Connectivity instead of Game Kit as GK is meant for games!  Core Bluetooth provides all the functionality necessary for a text messaging application.